# jQuery - Cycle alternate <li>'s?

Tags: jquery

on the site I am currently developing I'm trying to cycle through a load of `<li>`'s, but at alternating times. For example:

1. To start off with I'd be showing the first two `<li>` items.
2. Item 1 would fade out.
3. Item 3 would fade in, in place of item 1.
4. Item 2 would fade out.
5. Item 4 would fade in, in place of item 2.

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

[image: Steps 1-5]

Any idea how I can achieve this effect?
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you looked up any cycle plugins to do this for you?  (E.g. http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)

Comment: All you need is to cycle item 1 and 3 on position 1 and item 2 and 4 on position 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this (could be simplified further):

```
$("#items li").slice(2).hide();
var index = false;
setInterval(function() {
    $("#items li").eq(index).fadeOut(function() {
       $("#items li").eq(2).insertAfter(this).fadeIn();
       $(this).appendTo("#items");
       index = !index;
    });  
}, 3000);
```

This just gives that `<ul>` and id to make it faster to work work: `<ul id="items">`, [you can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/t3jcf/1/).  Before you ask, yes I'm blatantly abusing the weak typing to treat `index` as both a boolean and a `1`/`0` for the [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function.

What this does is:

- Hide any past the first 2
- Start with `false` (`0`) index, so we're changing Item 1 first
- Every 3 seconds (adjust as you want):

  - Fade out the current item, either first or second, alternating
  - Take the next in line (currently the 3rd item, 0-based index or `2` for `.eq()`) and insert it after where this one just was, fade it in
  - Take the one that faded out stick it at the end of the line
  - Change the index so we change the *other* one next time
  - Repeat in 3 seconds

Comment: Nice work, I tested your example with more elements and it behaves nicely even with an odd number of elements. Really though, I'm giving my +1 for the blatant abuse.